# How to fix Linux kernel/modules version mismatch?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, iptables

I have a Wandboard Quad booting from a SD card flashed with Ubuntu 15.10.

After I upgraded my distribution with:

```
$> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

my Wandboard looks like this:

```
root@smog:~# uname -a
Linux smog 3.10.17-1.0.2-wandboard+gbe8d687 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Apr 1 08:46:23 UTC 2015 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
root@smog:~# cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.10.17-1.0.2-wandboard+gbe8d687 (tjakowit@hikalxplm30) (gcc version 4.9.1 (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Apr 1 08:46:23 UTC 2015
root@smog:~# ls -l /lib/modules/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 May 21 20:05 4.2.0-42-generic
root@smog:~#
root@smog:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.10
Release:        15.10
Codename:       wily
```

As you can see, there is a mismatch between the kernel version and the modules version (from the upgraded rootfs), therefore commands like iptables will not work:

```
root@smog:~# iptables -L
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:578 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.10.17-1.0.2-wandboard+gbe8d687/modules.dep.bin'
iptables v1.4.21: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Please note that this command does NOT work in my case (from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/problem-with-iptables)):

```
$> sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-3.10.17-1.0.2-wandboard+gbe8d687
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-image-3.10.17-1.0.2-wandboard+gbe8d687'
```

How do I fix this problem, except for re-flashing my board with a clean image (and never upgrade it) ?

EDIT: output of command apt-cache search linux-image:

```
$> apt-cache search linux-image
alsa-base - ALSA driver configuration files
linux-image-generic - Generic Linux kernel image
linux-image-4.2.0-16-generic - Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
linux-image-4.2.0-16-generic-lpae - Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
linux-image-generic-lpae - Generic Linux kernel image
linux-image-3.4.0-1-hammerhead - Linux kernel image for version 3.4.0 on Nexus 5
linux-image-3.4.0-4-goldfish - Linux kernel image for version 3.4.0 on Android touch emulation
linux-image-3.4.0-5-chromebook - Linux kernel image for version 3.4.0 on Samsung Chromebook
linux-image-3.4.0-5-flo - Linux kernel image for version 3.4.0 on Nexus 10
linux-image-3.4.0-7-mako - Linux kernel image for version 3.4.0 on Nexus 4
linux-image-3.4.0-7-manta - Linux kernel image for version 3.4.0 on Nexus 10
linux-image-4.2.0-1013-raspi2 - Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
linux-image-chromebook - Linux kernel image for the Samsung ARM Chromebook.
linux-image-flo - Linux kernel image for the Nexus7 (flo).
linux-image-goldfish - Linux kernel image for the goldfish kernel.
linux-image-hammerhead - Linux kernel image for the Nexus 5 (hammerhead).
linux-image-mako - Linux kernel image for the Nexus4 (mako).
linux-image-manta - Linux kernel image for the Nexus10 (manta).
linux-image-nexus4 - Transitional package
linux-image-raspi2 - Linux kernel image for the BCM2709 architecture.
linux-image-4.2.0-42-generic - Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
linux-image-4.2.0-42-generic-lpae - Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
linux-image-4.2.0-1034-raspi2 - Linux kernel image for version 4.2.0 on ARM (hard float) SMP
```

Comment: What do you mean does not work? Share the output of the command pls.

Comment: @Hunter.S.Thompson I added the output of the command.

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache search linux-image`?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with this (is your `/etc/apt/sources.list` consistent?). But after so many painful experiences of similar kind with Ubuntu on ARM devices, I prefer to run only Debian on those, including my wandboard. If you re-flash it, choose a Debian *stretch*.

Comment: @GAD3R: check my last edit!

Comment: It sounds like apt removed the package of the running kernel. My understanding is that distributions normally prevent this, for the reason you show.  Might be worth a filing bug report.